# Openlayers 3 style a secondary geometry

Tags: geometry, openlayers-3

I've got a feature object with three geometries on it, main and two others.  Is there a way of styling each one of the geometries on a styleFunction pass?  If one is a point geometry and the other two are linestring geometries, how would I style all three in one styleFunction?

I've got as far as having the sub-geometries available and the styleFunction can switch them with a call to this.setGeometryName() but after that I'm a bit stumped - as the point geometry at this point has already been styled (there is an array of styles waiting to be sent back from the styleFunction).

Am I correct in thinking I can style the other two geometries as well, or should I have a separate layer with separate geometries and style them individually (this would add an overhead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add sub-geometries as named 'sets' of the feature (`feature.set()`), then call them via  `this.get('name of geometry')` and place that into an ol.style.Style call as the `geometry` parameter, then you can style it individually for that style.

Assuming your subgeometry is set on the feature as `subgeom`, your styleFunction could look like this:

```
function(feature, resolution) {
  return [
    new ol.style.Style({
      // main geometry style
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
      geometry: feature.get('subgeom'),
      // subgeom style
    })
  ]
}
```